# how to add onclick event to button in yii bootstrap(http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbButton)

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I want to add onclick event to a button in yii bootstrap (http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbButton)....

I am able to achieve this using,

```
<?php echo CHtml::button('Add task',array('onclick' => 'js:addtolist()'))?>
```

but I want to do it with bootstrap button,

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'button', 'label'=>'Submit')); ?>
```

I have a JavaScript function that I want to call on the button click event.

Thanks for the help in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onclick` event in `htmlOptions`, like below. `htmlOptions` is a array this will helps to add HTML attributes in tabs.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', 
      array(
        'buttonType'=>'button', 
        'label'=>'Submit',
        'htmlOptions'=> array('onclick' => 'addtolist()'),
      );
?>
```

Comment: Property "TbButton.onclick" is not defined.

Comment: I'm getting error - syntax error, unexpected ';' - Please help